# Symbolic links not displayed in Apache 2.4.54 WebDAV location directive with FollowSymLinks enabled

Tags: apache-http-server, webdav

I'm trying to access the created `symstore` directory through a WebDAV client (such as WinSCP, cadaver, Cyberduck or FileZilla) while connected to the `webdav` directory, but the symstore directory is not being displayed. When I access the webdav directory through a web browser, I am able to see the symstore directory, but I do not want to use a web browser as the final implementation for accessing the service. I want to be able to see the symstore directory while connected to the webdav directory through a WebDAV client.

Here is my current configurations for running WebDAV on Apache 2.4.54 and it works how I expect, with one exception which I will explain in more detail shortly:

```
LoadModule dav_module           modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module        modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule ldap_module          modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module   modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module   modules/mod_auth_digest.so

DocumentRoot "/var/webdav"
DavLockDB "/run/lock/apache/DavLock"

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-auth-basic-provider>
    LDAPReferrals Off
    AuthLDAPURL ${LDAP_URL} NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN ${LDAP_AUTH_BIND_DN}
    AuthLDAPBindPassword ${LDAP_AUTH_BIND_DN_PASSWORD}
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthzProviderAlias ldap-group ldap-group-auth-provider "${LDAP_GROUP_DN}">
    AuthLDAPURL ${LDAP_URL} NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN ${LDAP_AUTH_BIND_DN}
    AuthLDAPBindPassword ${LDAP_AUTH_BIND_DN_PASSWORD}
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
    AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 10
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute ${LDAP_GROUP_ATTR}
</AuthzProviderAlias>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    LogLevel ${LOG_LEVEL}
    ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/access.log combined
    Alias "/webdav/" "/var/webdav/"
    <Location "/webdav/">
        Dav On
        Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8 +FancyIndexing +FoldersFirst
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "WebDAV LDAP Authentication"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap-auth-basic-provider
        <RequireAll>
            Require ldap-group-auth-provider
        </RequireAll>
    </Location>
    Alias "/webdav/symstore/" "/var/symstore/"
    <Location "/webdav/symstore/">
        Dav On
        Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "ByteLoch-Symstore"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap-auth-basic-provider
        <RequireAll>
            Require ldap-group-auth-provider
            Require method GET CONNECT OPTIONS PROPFIND HEAD
        </RequireAll>
    </Location>
    Alias "/symstore/" "/var/symstore/"
    <Location "/symstore/">
        Dav On
        Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "ByteLoch-Symstore"
        AuthUserFile /run/lock/apache/users.passwd
        <RequireAny>
            Require user symstore
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am unable to see the symbolic link in the /var/webdav/ directory when I connect to the WebDAV share at the /webdav/ location through a client like cadaver or WinSCP. WebDAV protocol does not support symlinks that I know of, but I still expect the link to be still present in order for the rest of the configuration, which is defined in the location directive for the path "/webdav/symstore/" to be picked up. I just want it to see the folder, but does not need to follow the symlink. I have the FollowSymLinks option set in the configuration but even when switched to the directory directive, it is not working as expected. The permissions on the symbolic link, as shown by the ls command, seem to be correct:

```bash
# ls -ld /var/webdav/symstore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 13 Jan  8 23:09 /var/webdav/symstore -> /var/symstore

# ls -ld /var/symstore
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jan  8 23:20 /var/symstore
```

Here is the output from cadaver, when I connect in, as you can see when I list in the webdav directory the directory `symstore` is not appearing.

```bash
# cadaver http://localhost/webdav/
Authentication required for WebDAV LDAP Authentication on server 'localhost':
Username: .redacted.
Password: 
dav:/webdav/> ls
Listing collection `/webdav/': succeeded.
        .htaccess                              0  Jan  9 01:11
        compose.yaml                        2488  Jan  8 20:59
dav:/webdav/> cd symstore
dav:/webdav/symstore/> ls
Listing collection `/webdav/symstore/': succeeded.
        .htaccess                              0  Jan  9 01:11
        README.md                           1516  Jan  8 20:44
```

Looking at the logs on the Apache WebDAV Server....

```bash
# cat logs/access.log 
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:13:49 +0000] "OPTIONS /webdav/symstore/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "WinSCP/5.21.3 neon/0.32.1"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:13:49 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/symstore/ HTTP/1.1" 207 864 "-" "WinSCP/5.21.3 neon/0.32.1"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:13:49 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/symstore/ HTTP/1.1" 207 3148 "-" "WinSCP/5.21.3 neon/0.32.1"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:13:52 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 207 855 "-" "WinSCP/5.21.3 neon/0.32.1"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:13:52 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 207 2359 "-" "WinSCP/5.21.3 neon/0.32.1"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:14:15 +0000] "OPTIONS /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.30.2"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:14:15 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 207 686 "-" "cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.30.2"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:14:17 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 207 1730 "-" "cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.30.2"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:14:22 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/symstore/ HTTP/1.1" 207 695 "-" "cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.30.2"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:14:23 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/symstore/ HTTP/1.1" 207 2288 "-" "cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.30.2"
172.20.0.1 - .redacted. [09/Jan/2023:00:14:29 +0000] "PROPFIND /webdav/symstore/ HTTP/1.1" 207 2288 "-" "cadaver/0.23.3 neon/0.30.2"
```

Error logs display no errors, but happy to generate/share them depending on what might be needed for troubleshooting. I can set the log level to whatever is desired for more details.